# Team Foundation Service Hosted on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops

Is it possible to use Team Foundation Server as a service on a Windows Azure subscription? I know that tfs.visualstudio.com exists and I've been evaluating it within the company I work at however I'm thinking for personal projects that I work on at home. Is this possible to do as a service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[disclaimer - I work on tfs.visualstudio.com]

tfs.visualstudio.com is available as TFS as a service.  It's great for your scenario of working @ home on projects because it's in the cloud and available from anywhere.  It's also great for groups of folks that want to work together either in a connected or occasionally connected scenario.  It takes the burden of deploying and maintaining your own instance with high availability and management off of you and onto Microsoft's operations - it lets you and your team focus on what you want to do - write code and create product.

You asked about it being on a windows azure subscription.  To be clear, you're not deploying TFS on your azure subscription - tfs.visualstudio.com is a multi-tenant instance of TFS that you can sign-up for that's deployed on Microsoft's azure subscription.  The invitation codes have also recently been lifted so go ahead, sign up and try it out.

You could however get your own azure subscription and deploy TFS (basics or express) on VM in your own azure subscription.

The pros and cons are:

- tfs.visualstudio.com is currently free and gives you core TFS with little friction.
- having your own instance in your own azure subscription gives you more control - custom work item types etc...
- currently tfs.visualstudio.com offers the core features - source control and inthebox workitem types,  If you want sharepoint or reporting services (likely not needed for @ home projects) then you need to deploy your own instance on an azure vm.
- if you deploy your own VM then you have to maintain TFS (upgrade, patch etc...).  With tfs.visualstudio.com it just happens for you.
- on tfs.visualstudio.com you get access to newer features sooner (we ship to it every three weeks).

So, in summary, you can (1) deploy TFS on azure as a service if you deploy TFS on a VM.  Or, you can (2) be part of the multi-tenant tfspreview.com offering.  What you can't do is deploy your own cloud instance (azure web roles, jobagent worker roles, and sql azure DBs) on your azure subscription.

Comment: Is it possible to have two tfspreview.com accounts on the same live ID? If not I'll probably be moving towards a VM.

**EDIT** 
I signed out of tfspreview.com and went to get started... eventually I get to a page that says tfspreview.com only provides one user account currently.

Comment: I strongly recommend against the VM option if it's just a Live ID issue, you will need to stand-up the s/w (install/configure), open up public ports via Azure Load Balanacer, manage and patch the environment and also pay the monthly costs of hosting the VM, if its just for personal use then the overhead is way too much IMO.

Comment: I have a basic azure account from msdn that provides a beta for a VM... all the extra work that follows sounds fun.

Comment: Go ahead and try out tfspreview.com and a VM.  There's definately pros and cons (that @user pointed out) but there's still options.

Comment: Yes but when you want to use that MSDN Free VM for demo's or a play ground then you will be charged if you spin up another, enjoy!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all you have to do is setup a personal account on it (register again with unique namespace) , *note it's still in preview so it's  FREE, when it gets released there will be a cost, but I hope there will be a free tier for personal use/community like GIT, I think they mentioned something like this, free use under 5 users, I think that was on-premises but it hopefully should follow to TFS as a Service.

Brian Harry’s blog is a great resource for finding out the latest and greatest for TFS (on-premises) and TFS as a Service.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/

*Note I'm currently running two TFS as a Service accounts, one for my company (evaluation) and a personal one for my play projects.

Comment: How did you setup two accounts on tfspreview.com? Are you using two separate live ID's?

Comment: Yes and then I used an invite key off the first one to create the second one. I have been running this since Sept '11 when it went to preview.

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to check that :)